# Memory allocation, Singletons, and when to use/avoid them

Tags: c++, oop, language-agnostic, singleton

I came across [this page](http://www.object-oriented-security.org/lets-argue/singletons) which has a very nice, comprehensive overview of Singletons.

Instead of the common *"A Singleton is a class with a private constructor and only one global instance",* it describes a Singleton as follows:

> It's important to define exactly what we mean by "singleton".
>
> For the purpose of this argument, *a singleton is any mutable state which is reachable without starting from the stack* (i.e. reachable from static or global variables).
>
> Usually, a singleton is a class of which the author expects that there will only ever be one instance.  However, for our purposes, any object which is globally accessible counts.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> - A set of functions (or static methods) which manipulate some shared mutable state constitute a singleton.
> - If a singleton A provides a reference to mutable object B, then B is a singleton as well.
> - This implies that every mutable member of a singleton collection is itself a singleton.
> - A transitively immutable object is NOT a singleton even if globally accessible.  It is a constant.
> - A stand-alone function that does not access any singletons is NOT itself a singleton, assuming that code is immutable.
>
> ...
>
> #### What about open() or stdout?
>
> These are some of the worst examples of singletons!
>   ...

This means, essentially, that `malloc`, `new`, `shared_ptr`, or whatever your language uses to access heap memory -- all of these are using Singletons!

Yet, no one says we need to avoid heap allocation because of this. *Memory allocation* seems to be overlooked everywhere! Even on the page I quoted, they mention `open()` and `stdout` and logging, but they never mention heap memory allocation -- which is clearly more "dangerous" than, say, a logger, because it's not a one-way street.

So my question is, **is memory allocation an exception to the rule (why?), or is it *also* a bad example of Singletons?**

**How do I decide if a new use of Singletons falls in that same "exceptional" category?**

<sub>(Tagging as language-agnostic for obvious reasons, but also tagging as C++ since I think it's especially relevant to C++ because it lets the user modify the behavior of `new` and introduce more global state.)</sub>

Comment: That's an odd definition of singleton. It doesn't seem to include the "single" part of it at all. Edit: It doesn't nearly correspond to the actual definition of a singleton. =/

Comment: @sftrabbit: It seems to focus on the same issue with Singletons as you see in other definitions ("global state"), and memory management certainly involves a *single* (default) memory manager with global state, right?

Comment: Yes, all they have defined is global state.

Comment: Well, `malloc` (etc.) has no observable side-effects (other than the binary "could it allocate memory or not").  So it's not clear what advantage a hypothetical non-singleton `malloc` would bring.  But ultimately, there is only one address space (in a standard OS)!  That fact needs to be expressed somehow...

Comment: @sftrabbit: Er, what I mean is, is the memory manager in the runtime of every language an example of a Singleton? According to the definition above it is, but if you don't think so then I'd love to know why! (Answer perhaps?)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: `malloc` certainly has a side effect -- it can affect whether or not future calls to it return `NULL`! (Compare tht to the case of, say, a logger.) And that's why I mentioned C++, because in C++, `new` *can* have other side effects, if it's overloaded.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Indeed, I already alluded to the possibility that it could return `NULL`.  But that's because memory is a global resource, there's simply no way round that!  Similarly, there's only one CPU (or set of CPUs), so you could equally argue that CPU workload is another form of global state...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: CPU work isn't "state" though -- "state" is just another word for "memory". "Workload" isn't memory.

Comment: @Mehrdad: But I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for!  It's obvious that there is only one memory space, CPU, etc.  If you'd like to call that a singleton, then that's fine ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's state in the sense of coupling; two unrelated pieces of code could affect each other, if say, one of them presents a heavy workload, and another is measuring its own runtime.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I'm looking for an explanation of if/why memory managers in languages are Singletons, and if so, what distinguishes it from other global things such as `stdout`, that make memory management "okay" but makes `stdout`, etc. "not okay"?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I would say that okay/not-okay is really just a question of "Can this cause me problems?" and "Is there anything I can do about it?".  For something like output, the answer to both is "yes".  For something like system memory, not so much...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: That's a perfectly good answer I think, if you'd like to post it. :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, your program only interacts with one outside world. So no-one would argue that that's not an example of a singleton!

But from a software design point of view, I would say that okay/not-okay is really just a question of "Can this cause me problems?" and "Is there anything I can do about it?".

For something like output, the answer to both is "yes". In a complex program, there are considerable benefits (testing, dependency injection, etc.) obtained by encapsulating output in non-singleton objects. For something like system memory, not so much.

You can seek to abstract away some of the inherent coupling (indeed the OS, the language runtime, and things like custom allocators all do this to some extent in the case of memory).  It may also be helpful to encapsulate all of your memory allocation behind objects, to allow testing of complex application response to out-of-memory conditions.  But you still can't eliminate the global coupling entirely.